# Extent Report integration to existing selenium Framework

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I have a selenium java framework which is module based. Its existing and ancient. I am not sure how to integrate Extent report to it. It has allure reports and the output is in xml. People want html reports which are kind of shareable. Please help

Answer (score 0):

To integrate selenium with extent report:
Step 1 create blank html

```
ExtentHtmlReporter reporter=new ExtentHtmlReporter("HTML_Report_"+timeStamp+".html");
```

Step 2: create extent report object

```
ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports();
```

Step 3: attach extent report object to html

```
   extent.attachReporter(reporter);
```

Step 4:

```
testlog= extent.createTest("Report String");
```

Step5:
call these function to add steps and screenshots

```
    testlog.log(Status.PASS,"string description")
```

Step6:

```
extent.flush()
```

Create separate class for this report
for example:

```
public class Report {
    
     
     
    public void setup()
    {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());//time stamp
        
        ExtentHtmlReporter reporter=new ExtentHtmlReporter("HTML_Report_"+timeStamp+".html");
        
        ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports();
        
       extent.attachReporter(reporter);
        
        }
    
    public void createrepo(String TestCase)
    {
                
        logger=extent.createTest(TestCase);
    }
    
    
    
    public void tearDown() 
    {
        
            
        extent.flush();
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Do you have any repository like sample from where i can see the usage? Also do i need any other classes to be created?

Comment: How do i use it in my tests